# Entity Relation Abiguity

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I'm learning about entity relation diagrams (ER) and have a question regarding this. Say I had the following situation "A student can take multiple classes, but doesn't necessarily have to take any".

I'd have a set "student" (S) and a set "classes" (C). Say I want to define a relation "takes". I assume the relation "takes" would be many-to-many with partial participation. That is because a student can take multiple classes, and a class can be taken by multiple people. "Partial" because it could be that there are students who take no classes, and classes who are taken by no student. Is that correct?

Now, assuming I had a set "people" (p) and wanted to define the relation "isChildOfMother". I believe this is many-to-one? Because multiple people can have the same mother, but not multiple mothers, and one mother can have multiple children? But in this case, the relation would be pointing from set p to set p? How can I ensure it's read the right way? (Ie: Not in terms of one child can have multiple mothers but one mother can only have one child?")

I suppose the alternative would be creating a set "children" and a set "mothers", but what if somebody was a mother AND a child?

Comment: One mother can have more than one child, unless is in China.

Comment: Are you asking about how to represent such relationships in SQL?  Because otherwise, SQL has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a self-relationship or recursive relationship

In this case

- Each person can have only one mother or no mother.
- `Ana` doesnt have mother (orphan) or the mother isn't on the db.
- `Ana` can have more than one children
- `Alice` is mother and child

Person

```
id  | name  | mother_id |
 1  | Ana   |  null
 2  | Luis  |   1
 3  | Alice |   1
 4  | Jhon  |   3
```

For this you say `mother_id` is `FK` to `Person(id)`